# Django send filepath to views.py

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

In django urls how to send a file path and access the same from the view.I have tried the following below but i get an error,whats wrong with this code.

javascript

```
  window.location="/tagging/send_file"+data.filename;
  //which is nothing but /tagging/send_file/media/tmp/sssss.txt
```

urls.py =`url(r'^send_file/(?P<path>.*)$', 'send_file'),`

views.py:

```
def send_file(request):
 logging.debug("========================== Got file request")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding parameter to your view as

`def send_file(request, path):`